# Listview getChildAt crashes sometimes with using of getFirstVisiblePosition and getLastVisiblePosition

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to change style of the selected row in listview, if I click on another row inside listview I want to return normal style to the all other rows except the new selected one, I know I can use onItemSelected listener but it's not working with me so I change style when click on textview inside row.
The problem here in getChildAt returns null for some rows so app crashes when click some rows, I don't know how I can solve that I used all suggested solution about this problem but without give me any desired result at all time

```
for (int p = 0; p < listW.getLastVisiblePosition()-listW.getFirstVisiblePosition(); p++) {

                        if(p == position)
                        {
                           listW.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.focus_listview_row_bg);

                        }
                        else{
                            listW.getChildAt(p-listWO.getFirstVisiblePosition()).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.non_focus_listview_row_bg);
                        }


}
```

Comment: Can you add the crash logs?

Comment: @ArunShankar it is a java.lang.NullPointerException when the clicked item is located between one visible item and another one that is partially visible in listview

Comment: @MarkKeen, still crashing in some rows, Should I change something depends on your suggestion in this line?
                                listW.getChildAt(p-listW.getFirstVisiblePosition()).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.non_focus_listview_row_bg);

Comment: Assuming that your code is in 'onItemClick()' of the `ListView` then `position` will be the position in the adapter (your backing dataset) and not a screen position. `getChildAt()` returns the child at a _screen position_ not the adapter position, so you are mixing up the adapter position with the screen position. See [AdapterView.OnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html).